# Linq to populate ActiveDirectory

Tags: linq

I am a Database guy and dotnet novice who needs help with below UseCase

I am using LINQ to populate the DB but I am not sure how to insert/update ActiveDirectory using LINQ any sample code for doing that.

Most code samples on Google show how to query ActiveDirectory but not CRUD operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a "Linq-to-AD" project on CodePlex:

http://www.codeplex.com/LINQtoAD

That should hopefully do what you're looking for! So far, I've only ever seen it used to query the AD, however - don't know if it helps with inserting data.

If that doesn't help - check out these other resources:

If you're on .NET 3.5, go check out this MSDN article: [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx).

Otherwise check out this CodeProject article: [Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx)

Check out this [list of Code Samples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx) for System.DirectoryServices on MSDN.

If you're serious about Active Directory Programming in C# or VB.NET, go buy this book:

[The .NET Developer's Guide to Directory Services Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321350170)

[image]

Hope this helps!

Marc

Comment: I'll second this from Marc--particularly the link to Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5. I *love* the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace.